# SQL Import/Export Provider not Registered

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-office, office365, ssms

I am using SSMS "008 R2 on my Windows 10 64 Bit PC and when I try to use the import wizard to import from a spreadsheet (Office 365 ProPlus 64 Bit) I get an error message which says The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

I think this will only be resolved by using a newer version of SSMS...…. is this correct or is there another fix?

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the
[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920).

After downloading, you will find two installation files:
`AccessDatabaseEngine.exe` and `AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe`.
Choose the one whose bitness matches that of the installed
SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).